# JSF nested ui:insert - Component ID has already been found

Tags: templates, jsf, primefaces, facelets

Structure of my templates

**layout.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
...
<h:form id="headerForm" />
...
<ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
...
```

**integration.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<ui:define name="content">
...
<ui:insert name="tabContent">Tab content</ui:insert>
...
</ui:define>
```

**customerSide.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/protected/integration/integration.xhtml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:define name="tabContent">
...
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

When i go to the page `http://localhost:8080/dcc/pages/protected/integration/customerSide.xhtml`
i get this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID headerForm has already been found in the view.
```

It is not problem with headerForm. If i remove it it will fail on next component with id.
How do i nest these templates without getting the error?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest?

Comment: I am using primefaces 3.5.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: No i did not, i used another layout for xhtml files.